# Выбор типа данных для числа MySQL

Tags: mysql

Какой тип данных DECIMAIL выбрать для формата:

XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX - 7 цифр до запятой и 8 после

Comment: Должен подойти decimal (15,8)

Comment: Если нет необходимости СТРОГО ограничивать количество цифр до и после запятой, разумнее использовать максимально "широкий" формат, не увеличивающий объём места для хранения по сравнению с минимально необходимым. В данном случае это будет  `decimal (18,9)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) вроде всё сказано на этот счёт:

`DECIMAL(M,D)`, где `M` - количество цифр всего, а `D` - количество цифр после запятой. То есть в вашем случае минимально подходящий тип - `DECIMAL(15,8)`